# How can I compare two samples of percentiles?

Tags: sample

I have two data samples from a population. I want to find out, if values of certain attribute (BMI) are significantly different among the samples, i.e. whether the samples have same means or not.

If I had the measured values, I would simply perform T-test (for example) and  try to decide, if the samples have different means.

The problem is, that for each individual I have only the percentile, not the actual measured value. That is, instead of I had the BMI for each data point, I only have the percentile telling me, how is the (unknown) value compared to others.

I am pretty sure, that I cannot use t-test given these conditions.

Any ideas what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "percentile"? Would this be some given percentile of a set of measurements made on each individual? Or are you saying that you only know the rank of each individual within their sample?  It's hard to believe you might mean the latter, because that wouldn't provide you any information other than (possibly) the frequency with which values might be tied. Could you tell us in what sense these are "paired data," as you have indicated with a tag?

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear. Unfortunately the latter is the case. I updated the question so I hope it its more accurate now. The choice of tag was wrong, I am not really sure which tag should I use.

Comment: Let's digest your question to its essence: "I have two datasets for which I don't have any values.  How can I tell whether their means are different?"  I hope that putting it like this will make it clear there's nothing you can do.

Comment: This still doesn't make a lot of sense. It's possible nothing can be done, as @whuber suggests. It might help if you could provide an example dataset.

Comment: @gung Here's a typical example of what seems to have been described.  In dataset 1 the percentiles are $25\%, 50\%, 75\%$, indicating there are three values in order.  In dataset 2 they are $33\%, 67\%$, indicating there are two values in order.

Comment: I understand, that the data are not very usable. I was only wondering, if there is something that can be done and I am not aware of. @whuber yes, this is a correct example

Comment: Thank you for confirming that interpretation, Vojcek.  The problem is a bit more severe than "unusable": *you don't have any data at all* (apart from the two sample sizes). That's because (apart from the unlikely event of a tie or two) the sets of percentiles are completely determined by the sample sizes.

Comment: I did not realize it at first but it seems reasonable. Thanks for the answers anyway.